# Shortest expression possible in terms of other variables

Tags: trigonometry

Given, $$b^2\cos^2\theta +a^2\cos^2\theta =a^2\cos^2\beta+a^2\sin^2\beta\cdot \sin^2\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\cos^2\theta +\frac{b^2}{a^2}\sin^2\theta }\right)\right)$$

what could be the shortest expression possible for $\beta$ in terms of other variables?

(slight change in the last part of the question)

Comment: Well, to begin with, $\sin^2(\cos^{-1}(\sqrt A)) = 1-A$ ...

Comment: Well it went down to $sin^2\beta =\frac{b^2cos^2\theta +a^2sin^2\theta -a^2}{a^2cos^2\theta +b^2sin^2\theta }$, hopefully its correct. What could be the further simplification?